# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start at SONARQUBE

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am  trying to setup Sonar in my  localsystem and I have done creating the MY SQL DB , after that I also  created Default sonar schema too. Now while starting my Sonar Server ... I get this Exception,

```
2016.05.18 15:17:37 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.05.18 15:17:37 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.05.18 15:17:37 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.05.18 15:17:37 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:48) [sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:69) [sonar-server-5.5.jar:na]
```

I cant see any other issues at my  logs can you help me .

**Below are my versions ,**

- Java : JDK1.7
- SonarQube :  5.5
- Mysql :  1.2.16

Comment: Please provide full logs. Moreover what is the version 1.2.16 of MySQL ?

Comment: Fixed the issue , I have MySQL  5.5 and Sonar 5.5 , Sonar 5.5 was not supportive to MySQL5.5 hence degraded the version of Sonar5.4 and restarted the Sonar Sever ... Its works good !! .. thanks for the Reply.

Answer (score 0):

As Susheel Rao commented on his question, MySQL 5.5 is no more supported by SonarQube 5.5. Workaround is to downgrade to SonarQube 5.4 or to uprade MySQL.